# How can we limit the visibility of a pop-up menu in plugin.xml to only a particular folder and it's sub-folders? Does any such way exist?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, popup, plugin.xml

I am using `menuContribution` + `command` along with the `<visibleWhen>` element in my `plugin.xml`.

Say there is a particular folder "`XYZ`" in my Project Structure with subfolders "`xyz1`" "`xyz2`".
I want my popup menu entry to be only visible on right click of `XYZ`, `xyz1` and `xyz2` folders only.

Any inputs to do the same will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Abbas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<test   forcePluginActivation="true"
        property="testWizard.propertyTester.checkFolder"
         value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"
 </test>  is the reference to the property tester , which can be defined as
```

---

```
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
     <propertyTester          
        class="testwizard.wizards.MyPropTester"
           id="MyPropTesterFolder"
           namespace="testWizard.propertyTester"
           properties="checkFolder"
           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
     </propertyTester>
```

---

then the kind of folder and it's subfolders can be tested as below in

```
package testwizard.wizards;

import org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;

public class MyPropTester extends PropertyTester{

    @Override
    public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args,
            Object expectedValue) {

        IFolder folder=(IFolder)receiver;
        String folderPath=folder.getProjectRelativePath().toString();
        String arr[]=folderPath.split("/");     
        try {
            if(folder.getProject().hasNature(expectedValue.toString()))
            {
                if(arr[0].equals("XYZ"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to [define your own PropertyTester](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201017/), or to use a [predefined one](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions#Property_Testers), like the [**`ResourcePropertyTester`**](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.core.resources/src/org/eclipse/core/internal/propertytester/ResourcePropertyTester.java?view=co), which gets the path of the resource as parameter.